# How can I prepare Jack fruit to simulate the texture of pork?

Tags: meat, vegetarian

The best fake meat I've ever had was in Srilanka. 10 years ago I traveled to the Kandy mountains in Srilanka, where I had the most extraordinary non-meat stew. Jack fruit, potatoes, long onions, a strange circular bitter eggplant veggie thing, and other stuff I can't remember. This was stewed with cow bones on a open fire for several hours in a cauldron sealed with banana leaves and topped with a rock. Ok, the flavor did come from cow, but the texture of the meat was truly meat! If I didn't know that it was jack fruit I was eating, I woulda sworn it was pork!

Does anyone know how to make this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you, as I've had "pulled pork" jackfruit before at a restaurant.  I haven't made it myself, but [here's a recipe](http://chowvegan.com/2008/05/28/bbq-pulled-jackfruit-sandwich/).

The essentials seem to be to use canned, brined jackfruit, rinsed clean and squeezed free of water, then slow cooked for about an hour.  This recipe calls for "pulling" the jackfruit apart with a couple of forks, but this may be different from the texture you experienced in that stew--perhaps you'll get this texture that way, or perhaps you'll need to slow cook it for longer without pulling?